# Internal Server Error 500 after upgrade Magento version from 2.2.6 to 2.2.10

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, error, magento-upgrade, .htaccess

After I upgrade the Magento version from **2.2.6** to version **2.2.10**, I get **Internal Server Error 500** when I try to access the website.

I tried multiple solutions for example (a) removing var folder and generated folder, (b) changing the file permissions, re-run `setup:upgrade`, and `static:content:deploy`, but neither of these work for me.

One sort of working solution is if I remove the `.htaccess` from the root directory, then I was able to load the home page with js/css errors. But then when I go to any other page, I receive 404 error.

Can someone give me an advise?

Comment: First make sure you have php display_error set to 1. Then check the web console in network tab and go through all errors headers, you should get some meaningful php errors in there.

Comment: What is the 500 error? is it in the PHP logs for example? in app/bootstrap.php have you uncommented `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ?  You really need to know the content of the error for more help.